# How to mount Intel Matrix RAID 0 on Ubuntu 13.10 live?

Tags: mount, live-usb, raid

I'm not a heavy Ubuntu user. I have a Sony Vaio Z series laptop with two 64GB SSD disk working in RAID 0 (Intel Matrix - Intel Rapid Storage Technology) under windows 7.

The quest is to mount this RAID 0 volume under Ubuntu 13.10 live (started form USB stick) and then run clamav for viruses check.

I have read this: [Ubuntu 11.04 on Sony Vaio ssd Raid 0](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814341) and this: [ISW/FAKERaid - DMRAID : - Status:Broken](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682262) but I can't still understand how to mount this volume.

Can anyone please explain to me in plain English how to do it?

```
The result of fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x01ec5406

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    30359551    15178752   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    30359552    30564351      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30564352   250079231   109757440    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16013852672 bytes
78 heads, 14 sectors/track, 28641 cylinders, total 31277056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a36fb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        8064    31277055    15634496    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

The result of dmraid -s:
ERROR: isw: wrong number of devices in RAID set "isw_iffifahhi_Volume0" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
*** Group superset isw_iffifahhi
--> Subset
name   : isw_iffifahhi_Volume0
size   : 125040896
stride : 256
type   : stripe
status : broken
subsets: 0
devs   : 1
spares : 0

The result of: ls -la /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      60 Apr  6  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4200 Apr  6 14:01 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Apr  6  2014 control
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it out! It is very simple.

1. Start the laptop under Windows 7.
2. Use the Intel provided tool to unmark the RAID error on the one drive.
3. Boot Ubuntu from USB again and it is done. The whole volume will be automounted. And the error message

> ERROR: isw: wrong number of devices in RAID set "isw_iffifahhi_Volume0" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
>   *** Group superset isw_iffifahhi

is gone.